# Return int[][] array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

this might be an ridiculous question, but I don`t make it. I got two arrays this Type:

`String[] string{"A", "B", "C"}` and
`int[][] array {{1, 2, 3},{1, 2, 3}}`

and wish to get this output:

> A 1 1
>
> B 2 2
>
> C 3 3

I have almost tried every possible for loop, but it does not get in that order.
Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: What language?  What did you try?  How did it not work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// INIT ARRAYS
String[] abcArray = {"A", "B", "C"};
int[][] otherArray = {{1, 2, 3},{1, 2, 3}};

// LOOP ABC ARRAY
for(int x = 0; x < abcArray.length; x++){

    // PRINT
    system.out.println(abcArray[x]+otherArray[0][x]+otherArray[1][x]);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    String[] string = {"A", "B", "C"};
    int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3},{1, 2, 3}};

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(string[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This one will result in your desired output, as long as your string array has the same length as every int array in your 2d array. You can adjust the for-loops based on your use-case, but you'll get the idea.